# Get data from all repositories by specific criteria options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a tab "Today", "Tomorrow", "Soon", "All events" (and more).
Each tab has a criterion (rating, name, date of event), period (today, day, week, tomorrow, two weeks) and order (ascending or descending).
And I want to receive the data depending on the tab.
There are the following method:

```
private List<IEvent> GetEventList(int tab)
{
    var posterEvent = PosterEventRepository.GetById(tab);

    var criteria =  Enum.Parse(typeof (PosterEventEnum.CriteriaEvent), posterEvent.Criteria);
    var period = Enum.Parse(typeof(PosterEventEnum.CriteriaEvent), posterEvent.Period);
    var order = Enum.Parse(typeof(PosterEventEnum.CriteriaEvent), posterEvent.Order);
}
```

`IEvent` interface which is implemented by classes: `Film`, `Sport` and so on.
There is also a repository for each object: `FilmRepository`, `SportRepository` and so on.

How best to obtain data from all the repositories on specific criteria, period, order?
Reluctant to write as follows:

```
switch(criteria)
{
    case "Today":
    resultFilm = FilmRepository.FilmRepository.GetFilmsForToday();
    resultSport = SportRepository.GetSportsForToday();
    ...
   //then combine and sorting by rating
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a switch you can have a registry to register each criteria option and corresponding repository methods.
A registry can a key-value pair dictionary that has option name as its key and a list of delegated methods as its value.
Something like this :

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Func<IEvent>> _registry;

_registry.Add("Today",new Dictionary<string,Func<IEvent>>{{"Film",FilmRepository.GetFilmsForToday},{"Sport",SportRepository.GetSportsForToday}};
```

now you can easily register any number of criteria that can be added to your tabs and there's no need to change any other part of your code

Then you can replace the switch statement with this :

```
var methods=_registry[criteria];
resultFilm=methods["Film"]();
resultSport=methods["Sport"]();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) pattern, but realization will be vary depending of internal structure of your repos.

In general you will need iterate through all repositories and get all items which satisfies condition

```
switch(criteria) 
{ 
    case "Today": 
        var todaySpec=new TodaySpec();
        var result=repos.SelectMany(r=>r.GetRelevant(todaySpec)); 

   //then combine and sorting by rating 
}
```